# How to add iOS plugins to phonegap?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, badge

I try add Badge plugin, but it still not working. How to make it?
Or there may be an example project with Badge plugin?
Thx.

Comment: "not working" means what exactly?

Comment: @dan Function call is no effect.

Comment: if it´s not woking, fix it...do you have any error output? What have you done so far? How did you include the plugin in your project?

Comment: @dan in principle, as always :D
I just did it with the old tutorial phonegap.

Comment: I'm interested in this question, so I'll have a lookout for some examples for you.

Comment: @TomAx I also do this. I will be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [thorough tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html). Does this help?